# ContextMenuStrip not resizing properly

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu, toolstrip

When I'm changing text of a [`ToolStripLabel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstriplabel(v=vs.110).aspx) in my context menu, the context menu isn't resized automatically as it's supposed to be, when I change text of a menu item.
Looks like this then:

[image]

**How can I make the context menu resize properly?**
I could change text of a real menu item but I see that as a dirty solution.

---

**Test Form:** *(use left mouse button, left side and right side)*

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1: Form
    {
        private ToolStripLabel menuLabel;

        private void CreateNewContextMenu()
        {
            ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();

            // label
            menuLabel = new ToolStripLabel("hello");
            menuLabel.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
            ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add(menuLabel);

            // items
            ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("Test");
            ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("Cut");
            ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("&Copy");
            ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("&Paste");
            ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("&Delete");
        }

        protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            CreateNewContextMenu();
            menuLabel.Text = "hello world hello world hello world";
            Point p = PointToScreen(Point.Empty);

            // left
            if (e.X < ClientSize.Width / 2)
                ContextMenuStrip.Show(p.X + 8, p.Y + 8);
            // right
            else
            {
                ContextMenuStrip.Items[1].Text = menuLabel.Text;
                ContextMenuStrip.Show(p.X + ClientSize.Width - 8, p.Y + 8);
            }

            base.OnMouseClick(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, ContextMenuStrip doesn't recalculate layout when you assign the Text property of that menu item.  Arguably it should do it lazily but that looks borken.  You have to help, it is a one-liner:

```
    menuLabel.Text = "hello world hello world hello world";
    ContextMenuStrip.PerformLayout();
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a clean solution. Actually it **does** recalculate layout for normal menu items (`ToolStripItem`), just not for `ToolStripLabel`.